# how to make script that relaunch apps between in low and "retina" resolution on MacOS?

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra

Is it possible to make script that relaunch Lightroom or Photoshop between in low resolution and "retina" [retina](/questions/tagged/retina) resolution successively?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? This isn't really a platform to get other people to write your code for you, but help you with yours.

Comment: of course I don't want other people to write me huge code. I'm just thinking that there is a simple way to do it and maybe someone can share.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)